# mod_rewrite and not displayed picture

Tags: mod-rewrite

There is index.php and logo.gif files in my server.
I need to change the way of display an adress from `example.com/?nr=33&id=foo` to `example.com/33/foo` or `example.com/33/foo/`. I have type in `.htaccess` this code
`RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/([^-]+)$ /?nr=$1&id=$2 [L]`.

It almost works, but when I use `example.com/33/foo` logo.gif (with is used in index.php) dissapears in a browser. Can you show me mistake in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter a URL like `example.com/33/foo` in your browser, your browser will assume it is in a directory of that name, and request the (relative) URL `logo.gif` as

```
www.example.com/33/foo/logo.gif
```

Reference the image as

```
/logo.gif
```

and it should work.